# How to display Common posts from specific Tag & Category with Shortcode

Tags: posts, custom-field, shortcode

How to display posts that are common in Category A and Tag A, and I want to display posts by shortcode so that the Shortcode can be used on multiple locations with different **category Ids** and **Tags**.

I found the below code by google but don't know how to implement it in **functions.php** and not sure how to use it in the **shortcode**. I want to display Post **Title**, And Some **Custom Field** Value [For Example - Value A, Value B] in a **table** structure.

````
        $args = array(
        'category__and' => 'category', //must use category id for this field
        'tag__in' => 'post_tag', //must use tag id for this field
        'posts_per_page' => -1); //get all posts
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
       //do stuff 
        endforeach;```
````

Comment: Are you asking how to create a shortcode? Or how to retrieve post meta inside a loop? We have a 1 question per question policy, so be specific. You can always ask follow up questions on new questions

Comment: I want to display common posts from specific Tag A and Category A, But this should happen with help of shortcode. Apologize for the lack of my explanation skill.

Comment: I understood that, but you appear to be trying to do several things and combine them, but don't know how to do each part. You're asking 3 separate questions 1: "How do i create a shortcode?" 2: "How do I list posts in a category?" 3: "How do I display a custom field?", there are 3 separate questions, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function common_cats($att){
 $args = array(
        'category__and' => $att['category'], //must use category id
        'tag__in' => $att['tag'], //must use tag id for this field
        'posts_per_page' => $att['posts_per_page']); //get all posts
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        $output = "<ul>";
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
           $output .= "<li>".get_the_title(). "</li>";
        endforeach;
        $output .= "</ul>"; 
return $output;
}
add_shortcode('commoncats', 'common_cats');
```

use [commoncats] where you like to show the output of the above code.
above code will return a list of titles.

Comment: Hey @Muneeb, I have tried out [commoncats tag="32" category="5" posts_per_page="50"] But nothing display. I also want to echo the custom field values.

Comment: I have updated the check if it works for you, for custom fields; you want to display a specific field or all fields?

Comment: `category__and` requires an `array` of IDs, not just a string/number, it's the same with `tag__in `. This would be better with a `WP_Query` loop instead, and proper indenting

Comment: @PuneetVerma note that you will need basic programming skills to understand answers here, this isn't a place you can request a copy paste solution

Comment: @Muneeb, Specific custom fields not all, This works but I have implemented on page (A) but it's print that Page's (A) Title for 50 Times.

Comment: The loop does not set the current post as `get_posts` was used and there is no call to `set_current_postdata`

Comment: After implement `$post-> post_title` instead of `get_the_title`, all things working perfectly. Appreciates @Muneeb

Comment: @puneet you are welcome.

Comment: Now how to echo Custom field Value, and if all data should display in a table then what should be the code. In Table, There should be **Title, Publish Date, Custom Field A** as Head, and in `tbody` their Values. @Muneeb

Comment: for date you can use get_the_date( ''D M j''', $post ) reference for date formats. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/

Comment: echo get_post_meta( $post->D, 'customfield-id', true) ...

Comment: for table we need to update the markup a little bit, will update my answer later today.